# How do I transpose ASP.NET ListView grid layout?

Tags: asp.net, .net, listview

I'm new to ASP.NET and am trying to create a repeating detailsview type format.  By this I mean that the first column is a header type column and subsequent columns are the data records.

> Records     Rec1   Rec 2   Rec3 
>   Header A    Fld A   Fld A   Fld A
>   Header B    Fld B   Fld B   Fld B

I've tried a couple iterations of the following based on this [example](https://web.archive.org/web/20210616112920/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/010208-1.aspx):

```
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" DataKeyNames="FldA" DataSourceID="EntityRecordSource" GroupItemCount="3">     
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="Table1" runat="server">
            <tr id="Tr21" runat="server">
                <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                    <table id="Table2" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                        <tr id="Tr1" runat="server" style="">
                            <th id="Th1" runat="server"></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="Tr2" runat="server" style="">
                            <th id="Th2" runat="server">FldA</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="Tr3" runat="server" style="">
                            <th id="Th3" runat="server">FldB</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="Tr4" runat="server" style="">
                            <th id="Th4" runat="server">FldC</th>
                        </tr>                            
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Tr22" runat="server">
                <td id="Td2" runat="server" style="">
                    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowLastPageButton="True" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <GroupTemplate >            
        <tr id="Tr1" runat="server" style="">                
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Tr2" runat="server" style="">
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder2"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Tr3" runat="server" style="">
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder3"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </tr>
    </GroupTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="FldALabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FldA") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="FldBLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FldB") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="FldCLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FldC") %>' />
            </td>                
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

However this results in an error stating :

> System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCellCollection must have items of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell'. 'asp:PlaceHolder' is of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder'.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted basically the same thing, here is the method I wrote to accomplish this:

```
    internal static void TransposeListview(ListView lv)
    {
        if (lv.Items.Count == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("ListView has no items, so values cannot be transposed.", "lv");

        // first, convert the column headers into a first row
        var columnHeaderValues = (from ColumnHeader ch in lv.Columns select ch.Text).ToArray();
        lv.Items.Insert(0, new ListViewItem(columnHeaderValues, 0));

        var cols = lv.Columns.Count;
        var rows = lv.Items.Count;

        // create a list of ListViewSubItem arrays, to hold the target values
        var lvsiArrayList = new List<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[]>();

        for (var i = 0; i <= cols - 1; i++)
        {
            var lvsiArray = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[rows];
            for (var j = 0; j <= rows - 1; j++)
                lvsiArray[j] = lv.Items[j].SubItems[i];
            lvsiArrayList.Add(lvsiArray);
        }

        // now clear the whole ListView, and create the items and subitems using flipped row/column indexes
        lv.Clear();

        foreach (var lvsiArray in lvsiArrayList)
            lv.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(lvsiArray, 0));

        // last, convert the first row into column headers
        columnHeaderValues = (from ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvsi in lv.Items[0].SubItems select lvsi.Text).ToArray();
        for (var j = 0; j <= rows - 1; j++)
            lv.Columns.Add(columnHeaderValues[j]);
        lv.Items.RemoveAt(0);

    }
```